# pthread rwlock: rdlock inside wrlock

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, rwlock

Situation:

- Program is using `pthread_rwlock_t`, say `foolock`
- A thread, say T1, acquires the write lock (obtained using `pthread_rwlock_wrlock()`) on `foolock`
- T1 attempts to acquire the read lock (`pthread_rwlock_rdlock()`) on `foolock`
- No other threads possess either read lock or write lock on `foolock`
- There are matching unlock's.

What is expected to happen?

The program (T1, in particular) receives an error:

```
pthread_rwlock_rdlock() returns EDEADLK ("Resource deadlock avoided").
```

What is the motivation for choosing this behavior? What would be the problem if the read lock was granted?

What might be a good way to address this situation? Perhaps, T1 need to maintain some state that it already holds write lock on `foolock`. Any other suggestion?

My test platform is Linux 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64, NPTL 2.12

EDIT 1:
Few clarifications:

- I am NOT trying to upgrade read lock to write lock
- I am NOT trying to downgrade write lock to read lock
- I am exploring if request to read lock could be granted when the write lock has already been acquired.

Simplified Context:

- I am trying to provide two public APIs: (1) `find()`, and (2) `update()`
- `find()` employs read lock
- `update()` employs write lock
- `update()` implementation want to call find()  <<-- **problem**

My current approach is:

- Let each public API have corresponding lock free private version
- The public API does 3 steps:

  - (a) acquire appropriate lock,
  - (b) call private version,
  - (c) release lock

Answer (score 3):

POSIX is pretty clear that in pthread_rwlock_rdlock():

> The calling thread may deadlock if at the time the call is made it holds a write lock.

and in pthread_rwlock_wrlock():

> The calling thread may deadlock if at the time the call is made it holds the read-write lock (whether a read or write lock).

I suspect that this is to keep things simple.

The ability to promote a read-lock to a write-lock looks useful, but (sadly) it isn't.  Consider an "index" data structure where a "lookup" automatically adds values which are not found: when the lookup does not find a given value, it would be nice to promote the read-lock, and proceed to add the value to the index on the basis that nothing can have changed in the mean-time.  Unfortunately this would not work: consider two lookups which run at the same time, and both need the write-lock :-(  So, forcing the programmer to drop the read-lock and acquire a write-lock at least makes it very clear what is happening.

Mind you, if the "index lookup" has a problem if it can be holding 'n' read-locks at the point it decides it needs the write-lock, particularly if it has no way of kowing what 'n' is :-(  It would be nice to at least be able to discover 'n' by asking the rwlock !

In passing, I find that FreeBSD has:

> rw_try_upgrade(struct rwlock *rw)
>
> > Attempt to upgrade a single shared lock to an exclusive lock.  The current thread must hold a shared lock of rw. This will only succeed if the current thread holds the only shared lock on rw, and it only holds a single shared lock.  If the attempt succeeds rw_try_upgrade() will return a non-zero value, and the current thread will hold an exclusive lock.  If the attempt fails rw_try_upgrade() will return zero, and the current thread will still hold a shared lock.

...but I note all the caveats on when it will actually do anything !

---

On the question of downgrading a write-lock to a read-lock...

...the semantics are pretty clear if there are no pending write-locks.  However, if there are one or more pending writers, things are not so simple.

Currently, the programmer is forced to drop the write-lock and acquire a read-lock, and it is very clear what is going on.

If a "downgrade" operation were defined to be an atomic "write-unlock/read-lock", then that could let readers in ahead of any pending writers, or could only let readers in if there are no pending writers -- the second strikes me as the better option.  The "downgrade" has the advantage that after the downgrade, one knows that the state has not changed again -- I suppose that's useful.

If `pthread_rwlock_rdlock()` while holding the write-lock were defined to be a "downgrade" then it would need to be clear how many levels of lock that would result in.  If the result is two locks, would releasing the second (the read-lock) reacquire the first (the write-lock) or leave it read-locked ?  [If it were possible to "upgrade" read-lock to write-lock, how would arbitrary sequences of read-lock/write-lock/upgrade/downgrade/unlock be defined to work ?]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I am NOT looking for upgrade or downgrade, please see update in question.

Comment: OK.  The answer to the question "if request to read lock could be granted when the write lock has already been acquired" is, according to POSIX, that this "may deadlock".  So, for something portable, I suggest the answer is "no".  Your experiment with Linux suggests that it refuses the read-lock, but does not actually dead-lock -- I guess the state of the lock is unchanged, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

You already *have* a read lock, in that a write lock allows reading *and* writing.

So, what you're asking for is essentially a recursive rwlock, and the reason for not providing one is presumably that recursive locks are both more complex, and often indicative of poor practice in the first place.

If you really can't re-work your code so it knows what locks it holds, then I'd agree with your idea of tracking that state in some thread-specific struct. Something equivalent to the lock-guard type popular in C++ would be a good fit.

The separate read-to-write upgrade case has a host of other problems as gmch points out.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I am NOT looking for recursive lock, please see update in question.

Comment: Your write lock already grants the ability to read safely. Asking for another read lock when you already hold this is _analagous_ to a recursive lock, because you're re-acquiring something you already have. Youoriginally asked several questions, the ones I answered are _why does the current implementation do this?_ and _can I get the desired behaviour by doing this?_